# Flutter converting _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges() for Null safety

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am attempting to convert an old flutter code to a null safety code and encounter a problem with an abstract authentication class using firebase, basically its listening to a authStateChange

```
abstract class AuthBase {
  User get currentUser;
  Stream<User> authStateChanges();
  ....
}

class Auth implements AuthBase {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  Stream<User> authStateChanges() => _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges();
```

But after running the code it returns `A value of type 'Stream<User?>' can't be returned from the method 'authStateChanges' because it has a return type of 'Stream<User>'.` error
so what i did was cast it

```
@override
Stream<User> authStateChanges() => _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges() as Stream<User>;
```

But now i encounter a new problem `type '_AsBroadcastStream<User?>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<User>' in type cast` any advice on how to address this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_firebaseAuth.authStateChanges()
```

will give User or null so need to make it nullable as

```
Stream<User?> authStateChanges() => _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges() as Stream<User?>;
```

and also need to change in the base class as well as same.

Comment: I also tried this one but get `'Auth.authStateChanges' ('Stream<User?> Function()') isn't a valid override of 'AuthBase.authStateChanges' ('Stream<User> Function()').`

Comment: You also need to change in the AuthBase also  Stream<User> authStateChanges(); to Stream<User?> authStateChanges();